# Chat app with Laravel Echo and Pusher issues

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, pusher

I am learning to use `Laravel Echo` and `Pusher` and using [this article](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/) as basis. I am getting this error:

```
Class 'Pusher' not found
in BroadcastManager.php (line 216)
```

I can see `pusher` in my `vendor` folder. I have followed [instructions here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting) and installed `pusher` already.

My `.env` file contains all required `Pusher` keys and `config/broadcasting.php` is set up pointing to `.env`.

What have I missed? Thanks.

Comment: OK, so long day already... the [answer is here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052853/class-pusher-not-found)