# Class 'Pusher' not found Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, pusher

I've been battling with this for hours now

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   php artisan optimize

In BroadcastManager.php line 216:

Class 'Pusher' not found

have included 'Pusher' = Pusher\Pusher::class; as aliases but still having the error

Please Help!

Comment: at the top of the class have you imported the class using `use Pusher;`?

Comment: I have done that... still doesn't work. It works fine on my local machine, but shows the error on production

Comment: try to do "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: Done that severally... didn't work. I had to delete my production project and re-upload it, then ran composer update again for it to work

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution for this ?

Comment: re-upload your project..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'Pusher' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052853/class-pusher-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and fix with this command.

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-serve
```